# Dart accessing class fields like map values

Tags: dart, class, dictionary

I was wondering if it was possible to access the values of fields in an object with their names in a manner analogous to accessing values in a map with the key names. For example, something like this

```
void main() {
  MyData d=MyData();
  List<String> fieldNames=['a','b','c'];
  for(var name in fieldNames){
    print('This is the value of the $name field: ${d[name]}}');
  }
}

class MyData{
  String a='A';
  String b='B'; 
  String c='C'; 
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because Dart doesn't quite know what to make of d[name] because d is an object. But if d was a map, it would work. Like this.

```
void main() {
  Map d=myData;
  List<String> fieldNames=['a','b','c'];
  for(var name in fieldNames){
    print('This is the value of the $name field: ${d[name]}}');
  }
}

Map myData={
  'a':'A',
  'b':'B',
  'c':'C',
};
```

So my question is this. If I have a class, is there any way to treat it like a Map in the situations where I might want to refer to several of the field values indirectly via their names like I tried to do above?  Or is this sort of trick not possible in a compiled language like Dart?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".  The longer answer is "noooooooo". :)

But seriously, the namespace of your program code is very separate from the data values that are managed by your code.  This isn't JavaScript, where we can freely flow from code to data to code again.

Comment: Yeah, I come from a perl background. So if I can't do exactly this, what's the workaround?  I mean, some times it really IS more convenient to do the same thing to a bunch of fields in a loop, or maybe to write a function that does something generically to any field.  For example, suppose I want to make a form for editing the fields in an object. Do I have to hard code the field names?

Comment: I mean, do I have to hard code the field names again and again all throughout the code? Seems like a bug magnet.